# Swift: how to hide back button on the first view controllers of tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, back-button

My Tab Bar Controller controls 5 view controllers and I want that in those 5 main pages all the back buttons are disabled and not visible. How can I do that correctly? I have tried all Swift commands seen here in SO but none has worked up to now.

[image]

I have tried with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

but they don't work. I have also tried with

`self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`

but this is the strange result

[image]

Comment: `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` tried this?

Comment: @iAnurag see my update

Comment: Do u need navigation bar on all view controllers?

Comment: yes except for the 5 ones which are the main controlled by the `tabbarcontroller`

Comment: `self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` worked pretty well for me, I wonder why this is not working for you. R u sure you are calling it from correct viewcontroller?

Comment: Ehm, from which controller am I supposed to call it?

Comment: From all the five view controllers...in viewDidLoad

Comment: No it does not work...maybe because I have another Navigation Controller at the very beginning of storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105252/discussion-between-ianurag-and-lory-lory).

Answer (score 6):

To remove the "back" button from the navigation bar, you can create a UITabBarController class for your UITabBarController in the storyboard, and in that class, inside the ViewDidLoad() method, you can call

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

This will remove the back button.

Comment: This worked for me. It hides the back button preventing back navigation

Answer (score 1):

The back button is probably added by the *navigationcontroller* of the *tabbarcontroller*. So you will have to check the tabbar navigation controller.

Something like this:

```
self.tabbarcontroller.navigationcontroller.navigationitem.hidesBackButton = true
```

I think this will resolve the issue. Since the backbutton normally is added by a *navigationcontroller*, and not by a *tabbarcontroller*

**Update**

I have recommended him that he should loose the navigation controllers after the tabbarcontroller. Since the tabbar already implements the navigation needed between the different views. This and `hidesbackbutton = true` solved his issue

Comment: I am afraid this does not work too...I don't know why these stupid things force me to waste so much time...

Comment: Check if there is a navigation item in your story board. Click on the navigation controllers and look in the scene. is there a navigation item in it ?

Comment: there is a further navigation controller at the very beginning of the storyboard...before the login view controller. see my picture in my question

Comment: Can you try this in one view controller: self.navigationitem.leftBarButtonItem = nil ?

Comment: I get the result you see in my picture...back icon/arrow hides, "Indietro" is still visible but inactive...

Comment: Are you using push or detail segues ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105258/discussion-between-samueld-and-lory-lory).